# How do I solve this by R, with power.t.test maybe?

Tags: r

> A graduate    program is  interested  in  estimating  the average annual  income of   its alumni. Although    no  prior   information is  available   to  estimate the    population  variance, it    is  known   that    most    alumni incomes  lie within  a   $10,000 range.  The graduate    program has N = 1,000   alumni. Determine   the sample  size    necessary   to  estimate with   a bound on  the error   of  estimation  of  $500.

I know how to deal with it statistically, but I don't know if I have to use R.

`power.t.test` requires 4 arguments: `delta`, `sig.level`, `sd`,`power` (since `n` is what I want).

I know that `sd` can be calculated with 10000 range and = 10000/4 = 2500
but how to deal with the rest three?

Addition:
I googled about how to do this statistically(mathematically).
It is the book *Elementary Survey Sampling* by R.L.Scheaffer and W.Mendenhall. Page 88. StackOverflow doesn't allow me to add a picture yet, so I just share the link here.

https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=nUYJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=Although+no+prior+information+is+available+to+estimate+the+population+variance&source=bl&ots=Kqt7Cc5FFv&sig=Vx2bBRyi2KfrgMGkaC0f1EnfTWM&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

With the formulae provided, I can calculate that the sample size required to solve the question is 91. Anyone can show me how to do this with R pls?

Thanks in advance!
ps. Sorry about my crap English and crap format... I have not been familiar with this website yet.

Comment: Shouldn't you just compute the SE and set $N$ such that SE=500? You don't need `power.t.test` for that. Show us how you'd do it statistically.

Comment: @ekstroem I am not sure your method's gonna work, I just added a link to show how would I do it mathematically, take a look please : )